# Unmarshalling complex json in Go

Tags: json, go

So I am trying to fetch the analytics of an app by pinging and endpoint. I make the GET request which is successfull (no errors there) but I am unable to decode the JSON

I need to to decode the following json into structs

```
{
  "noResultSearches": {
    "results": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "key": "\"note 9\""
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "key": "nokia"
      }
    ]
  },
  "popularSearches": {
    "results": [
      {
        "count": 4,
        "key": "6"
      },
      {
        "count": 2,
        "key": "\"note 9\""
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "key": "nokia"
      }
    ]
  },
  "searchVolume": {
    "results": [
      {
        "count": 7,
        "key": 1537401600000,
        "key_as_string": "2018/09/20 00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For which I am using the following structs

```
type analyticsResults struct {
    Count int    `json:"count"`
    Key   string `json:"key"`
}

type analyticsVolumeResults struct {
    Count     int    `json:"count"`
    Key       int64 `json:"key"`
    DateAsStr string `json:"key_as_string"`
}

type analyticsPopularSearches struct {
    Results []analyticsResults `json:"results"`
}

type analyticsNoResultSearches struct {
    Results []analyticsResults `json:"results"`
}

type analyticsSearchVolume struct {
    Results []analyticsVolumeResults `json:"results"`
}

type overviewAnalyticsBody struct {
    NoResultSearches analyticsNoResultSearches `json:"noResultSearches"`
    PopularSearches  analyticsPopularSearches  `json:"popularSearches"`
    SearchVolume     analyticsSearchVolume     `json:"searchVolume"`
}
```

I make a GET request to an endpoint and then use the response body to decode the json but I get an error. Following is a part of the code that stays in my `ShowAnalytics` function

```
func ShowAppAnalytics(app string) error {
  spinner.StartText("Fetching app analytics")
  defer spinner.Stop()

  fmt.Println()
  req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "<some-endpoint>", nil)
  if err != nil {
      return err
  }
  resp, err := session.SendRequest(req)
  if err != nil {
      return err
  }
  spinner.Stop()

  var res overviewAnalyticsBody
  dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
  err = dec.Decode(&res)
  if err != nil {
      return err
  }

  fmt.Println(res)

  return nil
}
```

> json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field
>   overviewAnalyticsBody.noResultSearches of type
>   app.analyticsNoResultSearches

What am I doing wrong here? Why do I get this error?

Comment: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ is a tool you can paste JSON in and get an autogenerated struct

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** After you edited, your current code works as-is. Check it out here: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M7E0iG3hWSZ).

Original answer follows.

---

There is some inconsistency between the code you posted and the error you get.

I tried it on the Go Playground ([here's your version](https://play.golang.org/p/my_4sN7wPcw)), and I get the following error:

> json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field analyticsVolumeResults.key of type string

We get this error because in the JSON `searchVolume.results.key` is a number:

```
    "key": 1537401600000,
```

And you used `string` in the Go model:

```
Key       string `json:"key"`
```

If we change it to `int64`:

```
Key       int64 `json:"key"`
```

It works, and prints (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M7E0iG3hWSZ)):

> {{[{1 "note 9"} {1 nokia}]} {[{4 6} {2 "note 9"} {1 nokia}]} {[{7 1537401600000 2018/09/20 00:00:00}]}}

If that key may sometimes be a number and sometimes a `string`, you may also use [`json.Number`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number) in the Go model:

```
Key       json.Number `json:"key"`
```

Comment: Sorry about that I guess I copy pasted from an older commit, I have changed that field to int64 but I still get errors on popularSearches and noResultSearches

Like this `json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field overviewAnalyticsBody.noResultSearches of type app.analyticsNoResultSearches`

Comment: @LemmyKillmister But now your current code works without any modification.

Comment: No it doesn't @icza I have edited the description and pasted the whole function there please have a look

Comment: @LemmyKillmister Yes it does. Check it out here: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M7E0iG3hWSZ).